# On Windows is there an interface for Copying Folders?

Tags: c++, c, windows

I want to copy folder A and paste to desktop.

I am currently using C++ so preferably an OO interface if available.

Comment: What platform are you using? Windows? Unix? This apart your English is okay.

Comment: This is platform specific. What platform are you targetting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it works

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    system("xcopy C:\\Users\\Elmi\\Desktop\\AAAAAA\ C:\\Users\\Elmi\\Desktop\\b\ /e /i /h");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This assumes there is `xcopy`. Not necessarily the case on Windows Embedded. Also, this is not so much an "interface for" as "external program for". The other answer at least calls this approach a hack, which it is.

Comment: The question was for a C++ (Win32 possibly?) Interface to copy a folder inside a C++ program; using system() command is not a C++ interface, but invoking the O/S shell command.  Possible solution have already been provided on here (by Behrouz.M)

Answer (score 18):

On Windows (Win32), you could use [SHFileOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647743.aspx), eg:

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCT s = { 0 };
s.hwnd = m_hWnd;
s.wFunc = FO_COPY;
s.fFlags = FOF_SILENT;
s.pTo = "C:\\target folder\0";
s.pFrom = "C:\\source folder\\*\0";
SHFileOperation(&s);
```

Answer (score 10):

Use this

```
bool CopyDirTo( const wstring& source_folder, const wstring& target_folder )
{
    wstring new_sf = source_folder + L"\\*";
    WCHAR sf[MAX_PATH+1];
    WCHAR tf[MAX_PATH+1];

    wcscpy_s(sf, MAX_PATH, new_sf.c_str());
    wcscpy_s(tf, MAX_PATH, target_folder.c_str());

    sf[lstrlenW(sf)+1] = 0;
    tf[lstrlenW(tf)+1] = 0;

    SHFILEOPSTRUCTW s = { 0 };
    s.wFunc = FO_COPY;
    s.pTo = tf;
    s.pFrom = sf;
    s.fFlags = FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_NO_UI;
    int res = SHFileOperationW( &s );

    return res == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Starting with Visual Studio 2015 you can use [`std::filesystem::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy) which is even platform independent since it is available in implementations supporting >= C++17.

```
#include <exception>
#include <experimental/filesystem> // C++-standard filesystem header file in VS15, VS17.
#include <iostream>
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem; // experimental for VS15, VS17.

/*! Copies all contents of path/to/source/directory to path/to/target/directory.
*/
int main()
{
    fs::path source = "path/to/source/directory";
    fs::path targetParent = "path/to/target";
    auto target = targetParent / source.filename(); // source.filename() returns "directory".

    try // If you want to avoid exception handling then use the error code overload of the following functions.
    {
        fs::create_directories(target); // Recursively create target directory if not existing.
        fs::copy(source, target, fs::copy_options::recursive);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) // Not using fs::filesystem_error since std::bad_alloc can throw too.
    {
        std::cout << e.what();
    }
}
```

Change the behaviour of `fs::copy` with [`std::filesystem::copy_options`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy_options). I've used [`std::filesystem::path::filename`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/filename) to retrieve the source directory name without having to type it manually.

Answer (score 3):

(assuming Windows)

Use can use ShFileOperation (or IFileOperation::CopyItem on Vista).
Max.

Answer (score 3):

For a platform agnostic solution, I'd suggest [Boost::filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html).  That link is basically the reference material.  There is a `copy_file` method that copies a file from one location to another.

On Windows, the desktop is a special folder:

```
// String buffer for holding the path.
TCHAR strPath[ MAX_PATH ];

// Get the special folder path.
SHGetSpecialFolderPath(
    0,       // Hwnd
    strPath, // String buffer.
    CSIDL_DESKTOPDIRECTORY, // CSLID of folder
    FALSE ); // Create if doesn't exists?
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example using SHFileOperation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776887%28VS.85%29.aspx#example

Here's a quick hack without it:

```
#import <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    system("robocopy \"C:\\my\\folder\" \"%userprofile%\\desktop\\\" /MIR");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: He is using windows :) so: `system("robocopy C:\\my\\folder %HOMEPATH%\\Desktop\\folder /s /mir");`

Comment: It works, but why not directly using the Win32 API? You are effectively launching an external process, which itself will then perform the action using that very same Win32 API. This looks like a very complicate way of doing things to me, and also adds a dependency on an external program.

Comment: Never use system() call. There are windows apis for copying files and folders. See Max's answer.