# Copying directories with all its childrens using CopyFile function

Tags: c++, winapi

is there a way to copy directories with all its childrens (maybe from one logical disk to another) using winapi. `CopyFile` function copies only files. How i can do it? Maybe there is another winapi function designed for this task, or maybe there is a recursive solution with `CopyFile` and `CreateDirectory` functions?

Comment: To (let Windows) do it in one step, check out [`SHFileOperation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shfileoperationw) with [`FO_COPY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-shfileopstructw).

Comment: There are lots of options, which doesn't make this a terribly suitable Q

Comment: IFileOperation is the OS-provided solution, [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/master/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/appplatform/fileoperations/FileOperationSample.cpp).

Answer (score 0):

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725115/on-windows-is-there-an-interface-for-copying-folders)
Windows Platform: SHFileOperation. It is recommended to use [std::filesystem::copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/copy). Here is a sample:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem>
namespace fs = std::filesystem;
 
int main()
{
    fs::create_directories("sandbox/dir/subdir");
    fs::copy("sandbox/dir", "sandbox/dir2"); // copy directory (non-recursive)
    const auto copyOptions = fs::copy_options::update_existing
                           | fs::copy_options::recursive
                           ;
    fs::copy("sandbox", "sandbox_copy", copyOptions); 
}
```