Win32 copy files without replacement
I am currently using this answer to copy a directory in my code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11483739/14296133
I ran into an issue that this copies and replaces all the files with the same name. For example, if my target directory already has a file "test.txt" and my source directory has a different "test.txt" in it, the new contents will be copied over, but I want the old ones to stay. This means I only want to copy files that are missing in the target dir.
I looked at Microsoft's documentation and couldn't find any flag that copies files using SHFileOperation without replacing the existing ones. My question is whether this flag exists, and if not, what is the alternative? Preferably using the SHFileOperation interface.

FOF_RENAMEONCOLLISION: "Give the file being operated on a new name in a move, copy, or rename operation if a file with the target name already exists at the destination."

See also std::filesystem::copy  with options recursive and skip_existing ( std::filesystem::copy_options ).

@IInspectable this creates files like "test - Copy.txt", which I don't want. I only want to copy files that are missing in the target dir from the source dir, without changing those that already exist in the target dir

@artemetra Then it seems like the std::filesystem API is what you want. It's generally better to use standard C++ in any case.

@artemetra filesystem was available before C++17 in some compilers via the <experimental/filesystem> header (referring to your comment that you don't have C++17).

"I only want to copy files that are missing in the target dir" - That requirement is missing from the question. If that is what you need you should update the question.

I managed to get C++17 to work in my project, so here's the C++17 rewrite of the same function:
std::error_code CopyDirTo(const std::wstring& source_folder, const std::wstring& target_folder) {
  namespace fs = std::filesystem;
  std::error_code error_code;
  const auto copy_options = fs::copy_options::recursive | fs::copy_options::skip_existing;
  fs::copy(source_folder, target_folder, copy_options, error_code);
  return error_code;
}

